# Convert month name to Date range

Tags: java, date

I need to convert Monthname + Year to a valid date range. It needs to work with leap years etc.

**Examples**

```
getDateRange("Feb",2015)
```

should find the range  `2015-02-01 -- 2015-02-28`

**While**

```
getDateRange("Feb",2016)
```

should find the range `2016-02-01 -- 2016-02-29`

Comment: Can you use Java 8 and `LocalDate`?

Comment: What u have tried so far ?

Comment: Java 8 would be OK. The major problem so far has been finding out the number of days in a particular month. I looked at Joda Time but couldnt find anything tat did that. I can probably construct something that does it but I was hoping I could find something that was already written and tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, you can do that using [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html),

```
LocalDate firstDate= date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());

LocalDate lastDate= date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

If you have only year and month, it is better to use [YearMonth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). From YearMonth you can easily get length of that month.

```
 YearMonth ym= YearMonth.of(2015, Month.FEBRUARY);
 int monthLen= ym.lengthOfMonth();
```

Comment: Excellent! My knowledge of Java8 is unfortunately embarrasing, I guess I have to take the time to study it a bit more.

Comment: @PeterAndersson Note that `Month.FEBRUARY` is from an enum, and as such, an object. So you can pass that object as the value between your methods rather than the string "Feb".  Example: `getDateRange( Month.FEBRUARY , 2015  )`

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 made Date-Time operations very simple.
For Java 7 and below you could get away with something like this;

```
void getDate(String month, int year) throws ParseException {
    Date start = null, end = null;

    //init month and year
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    Date parse = sdf.parse(month);
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(parse);
    instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    //start is default first day of month
    start = instance.getTime();


    //calculate end
    instance.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    instance.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    end = instance.getTime();

    System.out.println(start + " " + end);
}
```

The output would be for "Feb", 2015:

```
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 EET 2015 
Sat Feb 28 00:00:00 EET 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 solution with default Java tools:

```
public static void getDateRange(String shortMonth, int year) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    // the parsed date will be the first day of the given month and year
    Date startDate = format.parse(shortMonth + " " + year);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startDate);
    // set calendar to the last day of this given month
    calendar.set( Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    // and get a Date object
    Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

    // do whatever you need to do with your dates, return them in a Pair or print out
    System.out.println(startDate);
    System.out.println(endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
public List<LocalDate> getDateRange(YearMonth yearMonth){
  List<LocalDate> dateRange = new ArrayList<>();
  IntStream.of(yearMonth.lengthOfMonth()).foreach(day -> dateRange.add(yearMonth.at(day));
  return  dateRange 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 provides new date API as [Masud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265660/masud) mentioned.

However if you are not working under a Java 8 environment, then [lamma date](http://www.lamma.io) is a good option.

```
// assuming you know the year and month already. Because every month starts from 1, there should be any problem to create 
Date fromDt = new Date(2014, 2, 1);  

// build a list containing each date from 2014-02-01 to 2014-02-28
List<Date> dates = Dates.from(fromDt).to(fromDt.lastDayOfMonth()).build();
```